# Several XPath for one XmlDataProvider WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xpath, datagrid, xmldataprovider

I have 2 `DataGrid` and one `XmlDataProvider` for XML-file. XML-file structure looks like this:

```
<Setting>
  <Element Name="..." Offset="..." ID="...">
    <Item Name="..." Type="..." Count="..." ID="..." />
    <Item Name="..." Type="..." Count="..." ID="..." />
    <Item Name="..." Type="..." Count="..." ID="..." />
    ...
  </Element>
  <Element Name="..." Offset="..." ID="...">
    <Item Name="..." Type="..." Count="..." ID="..." />
    <Item Name="..." Type="..." Count="..." ID="..." />
  </Element>
  ...
</Setting>
```

I need to display the values of attributes of all Elements in first `DataGrid`, and the values of attributes of all Items in second `DataGrid` using same `XmlDataProvider`.

XAML to display the values of attributes of all Elements in first `DataGrid`:

```
...
<Grid.DataContext>
  <XmlDataProvider x:Name="xml_setting" XPath="/Setting/Element"/>
</Grid.DataContext>
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="*" Binding="{Binding XPath=@Name}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Offset" Width="80" Binding="{Binding XPath=@Offset}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Width="80" Binding="{Binding XPath=@ID}"/>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
...
```

I tried to set the `XmlDataProvider XPath` value in "/Setting" and the `Columns XPath` values in "/Element/@Name", "/Element/@Offset" and "/Element/@ID", but only first Element is displayed.

How can I working with one `XmlDataProvider` to binding to different columns of different `DataGrids` to display the values of attributes of different nodes of the XML-file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you have to set the default namespace of the `XML` root node to empty string:

```
<Setting xmlns="">
```

Otherwise it will use the `xmlns` assigned in the window scope (which is of course `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"`) and the elements' Path will be incorrect.

To fill data for the second grid, you can bind the `ItemsSource` to the first `DataGrid`, the `Path` should be `SelectedItem`, this is exactly an `XmlElement` which is an `IEnumerable`. So you can use `XPath` to bind each attribute of each `Item` element to the corresponding `DataGridTextColumn` like this:

```
<!-- the first Grid -->
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="grid1">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="*" Binding="{Binding XPath=@Name}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Offset" Width="80" Binding="{Binding XPath=@Offset}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Width="80" Binding="{Binding XPath=@ID}"/>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
<!-- the second Grid -->
<DataGrid Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=grid1,Path=SelectedItem}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <DataGrid.Columns>    
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="*" Binding="{Binding XPath=@Name}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Width="100" Binding="{Binding XPath=@Type}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Count" Width="80" Binding="{Binding XPath=@Count}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Width="80" Binding="{Binding XPath=@ID}"/>      
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**Update**: The above code for the second `DataGrid` works OK for reading (showing) data but it does not support modifying. It's because of the way we bind the data, in fact the underlying collection is `ChildNodes` which is actually an `XmlNodeList`, this collection just implements `IEnumerable` interface. So it does not support editing. The underlying collection should implement the `IEditableCollectionView` interface. By changing the way of binding data we can set the underlying collection as an `IEditableCollectionView`. In fact the way `XPath` queries data can help us get an `IEditableCollectionView`. So in this case we try using `XPath` to get the underlying collection (instead of accessing via `ChildNodes`, which is implicitly enumerable via the `SelectedItem` of type `XmlElement`):

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="1" 
          DataContext="{Binding ElementName=grid1,Path=SelectedItem}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Item}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <!-- .... -->
</DataGrid>
```

Now it works like a charm (tested).

**Update**: To filter the Elements by Name, you have to use property element syntax (not attribute syntax) like this:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.ItemsSource>
        <Binding XPath="Setting/Element[@Name='SomeName']"/>
    </DataGrid.ItemsSource>
    <!-- ...... -->
</DataGrid>
```

Note that the above code is just an example of how to specify the `XPath`, the actual expression depends on the implicit `Source`.

Comment: Thanks for answer. The code works, but when I trying edit something in the second `DataGrid` `System.InvalidOperationException` throws - `"EditItem is not allowed for this view"`. What I should to do for solve the problem?

Comment: Thank you! But I have a question how can I showing data in second `DataGrid` from the specific `Element` without binding second `DataGrid` to first `DataGrid`, just showing all `Items` from `Element` with specific `Name` attribute value (for example, for this `XPath` string: `Setting/Element[@Name='...']`), I tried to set the ItemsSource value in `{Binding XPath=Setting/Element[@Name='...']}` but this is incorrect syntax.